# The Zig-Zag diagonal of a grid?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, terminology

If that was the diagonal of a square grid

[image]

Then, is there a common mathematical termonology of this diagonal ?

[image]

And what about this Zig-Zag digonal-like shape, is there a common mathematical termonology for it ?
[image]

By terminology, I mean a common name used in books and references to refer to these aspects.

Comment: For the second picture, I often hear that called the "antidiagonal", at least in the case of matrices. As for the third, no clue.

Comment: [Reversal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix)